# Scrapy / Parse several categories and subcategories with the same function

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a working (in most cases) code for scraping an e-commerce website. I start from an URL and crawl main categories, then go one lawyer deep to crawl subcategories, and do the same thing again until I land on products page.

It looks like this :

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_bot"  # how we have to call the bot
    start_urls = ["https://......html"]

def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.css('div.mvNavSub ul li a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_on_categories) #going to one layer deep from landing page

def parse_on_categories(self, response):
    for link in response.css('div.mvNavSub ul li a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_on_subcategories) #going to two layer deep from landing page

def parse_on_subcategories(self, response):
    (same code than above)

def parse_data(self, response):
    (parse data)
```

I noticed than for some parts of the website, I have to go deeper on subcategories to be able to parse products. As I'm always reusing the same code to crawl categories, I wonder if there was possible to just reuse the first function, until there is no more categories to crawl. Here is what I tried :

```
def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.css('div.mvNavSub ul li a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield response.follow(link, callback = self.parse_on_categories)

def parse_on_categories(self, response):
    if response.css('div.mvNavSub ul li a::attr(href)').extract(): # if there is categories to crawl
        self.parse(response)
    else:
        self.parse_data(response)

def parse_data(self, response):
```

If there is categories to crawl, I would like parse_on_categories to call the first function. If there isn't, parse_data should be called.

But for now I can't make it works, so if you could put me on the track it would be really appreciated :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to yield whatever you receive from parse() and parse_data() methods.

```
def parse_on_categories(self, response):
    if response.css('div.mvNavSub ul li a::attr(href)').extract():
        callback = self.parse
    else:
        callback = self.parse_data

    for r in callback(response):
        yield r
```